# Ansible populating a variable based on hostname

Tags: ansible

I've googled but I can't find a solution to what I'm trying to do.

I want to set a jinja2 variable based on the hostname of a server (I'm using different certs and want to have ansible create the `ssl.conf` based on the hostname).

I'd like a dict to do something like:

```
Certmapping:
  host1: www.mydomain.com
  host2: beta.mydomain.com
  host3: partner.mydomain.com
```

And then a template that references the dict so:

```
SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/<domain>.crt
```

I could have a monsterous:

```
if {{ ansible_hostname }} == 'host1' ...
```

But that looks way less elegant.

Comment: Perhaps you'd be better off defining a host variable called "domain", rather than defining a dict?

Comment: What's wrong with `host_vars`?

Comment: @MichaelHampton are you suggesting having something like:

Comment: @MichaelHampton are you suggesting having something like:

[host1]
10.0.0.5

[host1:vars]
domain: www.mydomain.com

...in my /etc/ansible/hosts file

I'm pretty new to Ansible in general, so I may be missing someting...

Comment: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html#host-variables

Answer (score 3):

Following up on the indefatigable @michaelhampton’s suggestion, here is how you use `host_vars`

```
project root
-- host_vars
   -- host1.yml
   -- host2.yml
   -- host3.yml
-- my_playbook.yml
```

So when you set up host1.yml, you can just put the value it needs there:

```
---
Certmap: www.mydomain.com
```

And when you need to access it, you just refer to it like:

```
{{ Certmap }}
```

It will change for different hosts so long as each host has a host_vars file with `Certmap` defined.

Comment: Note that `host_vars` is a directory, holding those files.

Answer (score 0):

Given your `Certmapping` dictionary, just use the following:

```
- set_fact:
    certificate_configuration_line: "SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/{{Certmapping[ansible_hostname]}}.crt"
```

(`set_fact` is just as an example, you can use the reference directly in `lineinfile` or a Jinja2 template)