# How can I set an Ansible variable depending on hostname?

Tags: ansible

If I run `ansible-playbook playbooks/snapshot.yml -l my.host.net` I want to reference a `VMID` variable which is pre-set to this hosts virtual machine ID (4321 for instance).

I've found [a question](https://serverfault.com/questions/821385/ansible-populating-a-variable-based-on-hostname) that should have answered this, however when I add `my.host.net.yml`(below) to a `host_vars` directory under my project, I get the error `...'VMID' is undefined` when running the playbook. Either ansible isn't automatically reading `host_vars/my.host.net.yml` or I've got something messed.

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:

  - name: print a host variable
    debug:
      msg: "hostvar VMID is {{ VMID }}"
```

**host_vars/my.host.net.yml**

```
---
VMID: 4321
```

**Update - Added directory structure:**

```
ansible
├── ansible.cfg
├── group_vars
├── host_vars
│   └── my.host.net.yml
├── inventories
├── playbooks
│   └── snapshot.yml
├── roles
└── tests
```

Comment: That's odd, I would have expected Ansible to read the variable. Maybe your [playbook-vars-root](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#playbook-vars-root) is set to a different path? I would suggest to export `playbook-vars-root` parameter with the correct path on the cmd and see if things change.

Comment: Hrm.. so maybe a path issue? I moved the playbook out of the `playbooks` directory and into the ansible root (`host_vars` directly below the playbook) and it did work correctly. If I put the playbook back, I can only get it working by adding `vars_files: ../host_vars/my.host.net.yml` to the playbook which seems like I have some path set wrong in `ansible.cfg`. I'll look into `playbook-vars-root` (set to 'top' and 'all' in ansible.cfg but made no diff)

Comment: I would recommend to set those paths in a `ansible.cfg` at root of the playbook.

Comment: Looks like I need to define the `host_vars` paths as relative paths in my playbook since I opted to use a `playbooks` subdirectory (see updated tree structure above) to keep the root less cluttered. https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/1353/playbook-without-relative-path-to-vars

Comment: Just remove the yml ending.Host var should be the same as the name/ip (depends how you target it) of the system.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else running across this, I ended up putting symlinks in my `playbooks` directory. I didn't realize when setting up ansible that putting playbooks in a different directory would cause these issues. I sure don't want hundreds of playbooks cluttering the ansible root however so this works. I could do the same with `group_vars` as it's in my playbooks as `vars_files: ../group_vars/` but for now that seems OK.

```
ansible
├── ansible.cfg
├── group_vars
├── host_vars
│   └── my.host.net.yml
├── inventories
├── templates
├── playbooks
│   ├── snapshot.yml
│   ├── templates -> ../templates 
|   └── host_vars -> ../host_vars
├── roles
└── tests
```

Comment: I have no idea how you managed to add 'host_vars' twice :)

Comment: Ah! Yeah, good catch.  Not sure how it got there. Fixed!